# Error while installing magento 2.4 with php8

Tags: magento2.4.1

I am installing magento 2.4.1 with php8 and it is giving me following error

```
Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in C:\xampp\htdocs\m2\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php on line 34
```

please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This error is because Magento 2 does not support PHP 8 yet. So you need to install xampp with the PHP version of 7.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try

1- add php 8 to your composer.json (keep v7.4)

`"php": "^7.4|^8.0"`,

2- `composer update`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer to the documentation guide for installing magento 2.4:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html#php

Answer (score 0):

Till date, Magento has not released any stable/compatible release that can run on PHP 8.0 but if developer wants to give a try using following way to setup Magento in environment.

For this Magento has created separate [branch](https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/php8-develop) based on Magento 2.4.1 on their github account.

You can setup project by following steps:

```
1. create folder named m2-php8
2. cd C:\xampp\htdocs\m2-php8
3. git clone --single-branch --branch php-develop https://github.com/magento/magento2/tree/php8-develop .
4. you can run setup commands as usual
```

**NOTE: You can not use this code in production as this branch(php8-develop) is still under DEVELOPMENT.**